# Best way to display image in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-3.5, image-processing

Currently I'm working on a Ultrasound scanning project, which displays the continues images aquired from a probe, to do that I'm writing following code.

XAML:

```
<Image Name="imgScan" DataContext="{Binding}" Source="{Binding Path=prescanImage,Converter={StaticResource imgConverter}}" />
```

C# Assignment:

```
Bitmap myImage = GetMeImage();
imageMem = new MemoryStream();
myImage .Save(imageMem, ImageFormat.Png);
imgScan.DataContext = new { prescanImage = imageMem.ToArray() };
```

Converter:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    if (value != null && value is byte[])
    {
      byte[] ByteArray = value as byte[];
      BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage();
      bmp.BeginInit();
      bmp.StreamSource = new MemoryStream(ByteArray);
      bmp.EndInit();
      return bmp;
    }
    return null;
}
```

This method is costing me lot of (performance), 
is there any better way to do it??

Comment: Is the Convert method itself costing a lot of performance on each run, or is it just being polled too often? I'm curious if a custom control to handle this would be the better approach (as it is a constant stream of images).

Comment: Would suggest any custome/thirdparty controls... or can we stream the Bitmap images

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're already setting the `DataContext` in code (not xaml), why not just skip a few steps?

```
Bitmap myImage = GetMeImage();
imageMem = new MemoryStream();
myImage.Save(imageMem, ImageFormat.Png);
BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage();
bmp.BeginInit();
bmp.StreamSource = new MemoryStream(imageMem.ToArray());
bmp.EndInit();
imgScan.Source = bmp;
```

If you have access to `GetMeImage()`, you may want to consider altering it to better fit into your application - Does it really need to return a `Bitmap`?

Also, how often is your first piece of code being executed? You may want to consider altering that, or allowing it to vary when it needs to.

Comment: Thanks for response... I really dont have access to GetMeImage() and returns only Bitmap :( The code has to run every 500ms...